# access a cross domain iframe history.length or get its text in a variable on the parent document

Tags: jquery, security

I have a feedback pop up (TickBox) that loads a cross domain `iFrame` and when submitting the form it loads the "thanks for...." page.

I want that when user submits the feedback button it should hide the `iFrame` wrapper.

I know that because of the "same origin policy" security limitations you cant get the actual location of the `iFrame` when it changes.

My question is, can i somehow get the history via `history.length` to check if this is a new location?

Or maybe read its content and find the new page text (like: "thanks for") and hide its wrapper

```
$("iframe").load(function(){
    var iframeSrc = $(this).contents()[0].location.hash; /*or history.length */
    var isSubmitedUrl = /Home_Landing/
    var testUrl = iframeSrc.search(isSubmitedUrl)

  if(testUrl >= 0){    /*or if(history.length >= 0)*/
    $(".iframeWrap").hide();
  }

 })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) not only restricts access to the `iframe` location but the entire `window` object for that iframe.

So if you can't get to the iframe's `window`, you can't get to the iframe's `window.history` property.

You cannot even read the `src` property on the iframe in your own document, as it does not reflect the changes in the location of the iframe.

The best I can think of is to pass the iframe's url through a proxy on your own server, in which case you'd be able to at least access it's DOM and listen for `"onsubmit"` of the embedded `form`, to hide your wrapper.

Comment: Thanks much, can you please say a few more words, (or post a link) to explain a bit more the solution of passing iframe's url proxy on own server

Comment: @Eliazer: what server-side technology are you using? php, asp.net etc.

Comment: in this project i am using asp.net

Comment: @Eliazer Braun: here's how to do it in asp.net: https://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/archive/2008/04/14/fast-streaming-ajax-proxy-continuously-download-from-cross-domain.aspx

Comment: @RoatinMarth the link is broken.