# can not get html inside iframe , and can not fire events of elements inside iframe

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

i am using Facebook graph API to invite Facebook friends to my codeigniter application , i want to fire a click event inside an element of iframe , but it is not firing , my code is

```
        $("iframe").contents().find('input[name="login"]').live('mouseover',function(){
                          alert("log in");
         });
```

alert is not shown , no errors in firebug .

but if i do this

```
    $("iframe").live('mouseover',function(){
                      alert("log in");
     });
```

this works and give the alert .

but if i try to get html inside iframe

```
$("iframe").live('mouseover',function() {          
   alert($('.fb_ltr').contents().find('.request').html());                      
});


it gives an error in firebug 


Permission denied to access property 'ownerDocument'
[Break On This Error] shift(),i.sort());if(!!e&&!f.event.cus...is).get();f(e[h])[b](j),d=d.concat(j
```

how to use elements inside iframe , i saw similar questions , but could not get a help . please help , thanks ..............................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are unable to access/manipulate any content via iframe if it's from a different domain.

[jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

The Iframe is treated as a single element.

Thats why your code:

```
$("iframe").live('mouseover',function(){});
```

works but accessing its element won't

see this
[jQuery - Trying to select element from iFrame (point and click)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577630/jquery-trying-to-select-element-from-iframe-point-and-click)